# Duplicate line (or selected text) in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

After I reinstalled VS (after upgrading to Windows 10), I found out I can't assign a shortcut keys to the command duplicate, I already made it before in the same version: I assigned <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to that command, but now I can't find it.

[image]
I don't want to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>, It's not what I want as it uses the clipboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have tried this already but have you tried selecting the "press shortcut keys" text box and pressing ctrl-d.

I have windows 10 and VS 2015 and it works for me.

Here is my experience...
[image]

then after clicking Assign...
[image]

Maybe try rebooting your PC also.